# why I Can't Load Image in My HTML Project?

Tags: html, css, image, video, hyperlink

I dont why on HTML when I put a image on the html when I open the file it doesn't load in browser!! but when I Open it in Live server it work in vs code, and CSS doesnt work on the browser

I tried to made video and image contact them with CSS but My Html project dont load image and CSS it is Only Work on live server in vs code
here is my code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS Stayle/CSSStyle.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS Stayle/Shapes.css">
```

to link with CSS

and here my code to src the image

```
   <img id="CourseFormant" src="/photo/4th.png" alt="fourth Course">
```

Comment: you can use this as src `src="photo/4th.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Change your src from
/photo/4th.png to photo/4th.png

This works only if your HTML File is in root directory.